# pyspark 1.6.0 write to parquet gives "path exists" error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I read in from parquet file(s) from different folders, take e.g. February this year (one folder = one day)

```
indata = sqlContext.read.parquet('/data/myfolder/201602*')
```

do some very simple grouping and aggregation

```
outdata = indata.groupby(...).agg()
```

and want to store again.

```
outdata.write.parquet(outloc)
```

Here is how I run the script from bash:

```
spark-submit 
  --master yarn-cluster 
  --num-executors 16 
  --executor-cores 4 
  --driver-memory 8g
  --executor-memory 16g 
  --files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml  
  --driver-java-options 
  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
  spark_script.py
```

This generates multiple jobs (is that the right term?). First job runs successfully. Subsequent jobs fail with the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spark_generate_maps.py", line 184, in <module>
    outdata.write.parquet(outloc)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 471, in parquet
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 51, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'path OBFUSCATED_PATH_THAT_I_CLEANED_BEFORE_SUBMIT already exists.;'
```

**When I give only one folder as input, this works fine.**

**So it seems the first job creates the folder, all subsequent jobs fail to write into that folder. Why?**

just in case this could help anybody:

**imports:**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, collect_list, countDistinct, count
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
import numpy as np
import sys
import math
```

**config:**

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('spark-compute-maps').setMaster('yarn-cluster')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

Answer (score 14):

Your question is "why does Spark iterate on input folders, but applies the default `write` mode, that does not make sense in that context".

Quoting the [Spark V1.6 Python API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame)...

> `mode(saveMode)`
>      Specifies the behavior when data or table already exists.
>      Options include:
>        *append*   Append contents of this DataFrame to existing data.
>        *overwrite* Overwrite existing data.
>        *error*       Throw an exception if data already exists.
>        *ignore*    Silently ignore this operation if data already exists.

I think `outdata.write.mode('append').parquet(outloc)` is worth a try.

Answer (score 4):

You should add mode option in your code.

```
outdata.write.mode('append').parquet(outloc)
```